# 'The certificate bundleId did not match that of your app' Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to integrate remote push notifications in iOS using Firebase, but I have run into an issue. When I upload my Development APNs Certificates, I get this error: 'The certificate bundleId did not match that of your app.' I don't understand why I am getting this issue and some help would be much appreciated. For some context, the file I am uploading is called 'Certificates.p12.' This was created when I exported my Certificate downloaded from my developer account. One possible issue I found is that I might have to upload a file called 'CertificateRemoteNotifs.p12.' The only issue with this is that no such file exists on my computer and I am not quite sure as to how I could get one. Other than that, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is much better if you switch from Certificates to keys. 
Check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs) how to generate it.